# How I configure Vim for use with netrw?

Tags: netrw, save

I recently started to use `netrw` as a file manager next to my editing session.  But I had a coupe of issues with it.

First of all `netrw` reads unhidden buffers from the disk every time.  Which made me lose changes when I left a file (without writing it) and then came back to it.  Therefore I needed to `set hidden`.  (Not sure whether that is correct but I did not investigate further.)

But now I have an issue with `:wall`.  Let's say I have these two files:

```
echo foo > foo
echo bar > bar
echo foobar > fooba
```

I open one of them with

```
vim -u ~/.testvimrc foo
```

Where `.testvimrc` looks as follows:

```
let g:netrw_liststyle=3
let g:netrw_chgwin=2
let g:netrw_winsize=22
set nocompatible
set hidden
set noautowrite
```

I edit `foo` do not write it.  And open `netrw`:

```
:22Lexplore
```

And open the `bar` file using the `netrw` window.  I then edit `bar` and do not write it either.  I notice that I forgot the `r` in the last file `fooba`, therefore I go into the `netrw` window (`<c-w><c-w>`) and press `R` to rename the file `fooba` -> `foobar`.

Finally I do:

```
:wall
```

To write everything but then Vim writes an extra file.  The final file listing looks as follows:

```
bar
foo
foobar
NetrwTreeListing 1
```

---

This only happens when I have `netrw` configured.  If I comment the `netrw` lines out:

```
"let g:netrw_liststyle=3
"let g:netrw_chgwin=2
"let g:netrw_winsize=22
set nocompatible
set hidden
set noautowrite
```

And perform the same procedure I do not get the `NetrwTreeListing 1` file.

---

This is a MCVE, in a real world editing I often get dozens of those `NetrwTeeListing *` files after a session of editing ans renaming files.

I am confident I'm configuring `netrw` wrong.  I have been using it just for a couple of days, so I'm a little clueless on its configuration.  On the other hand I'm confident that the `netrw` listings are `readonly` buffers, therefore `:wall` shall not be writing them (contrary to `:wall!`).

What I'm doing wrong?  I'm tired of removing those `NetrwTreeLisitng *` files after an editing session.

---

Extra note: I renamed my `~/.vim` directory for the MCVE (`mv ~/.vim ~/.old-vim`) to make sure plugins are not interfering.

---

#### Update

It does look like a bug.  A new buffer is created every time a refresh happens on the tree listing (`let g:netrw_liststyle=3`) in `netrw.vim`.  The refresh happens in `s:NetrwRefresh`, specifically in the lines 8502-8507 (in the newest `netrw` available):

```
sil! NetrwKeepj %d _
if a:islocal
 NetrwKeepj call netrw#LocalBrowseCheck(a:dirname)
else
 NetrwKeepj call s:NetrwBrowse(a:islocal,a:dirname)
endif
```

If I enter `netrw` in tree list mode and hit any command that triggers a refresh (`R`, `r`, `D`) that code runs and produces a modified buffer.  The output of `:buffers!` after a refresh looks as follows:

```
:buffers!                           
  1 #a   "foo"                          line 0
  2u h + "NetrwTreeListing 1"           line 1
  4u%a-  "NetrwTreeListing 2"           line 8
  5u     "NetrwTreeListing"             line 1
```

Note the `h +` next to the old listing.  I'm continuing the investigation. (I'm using this question as a scratch pad for notes about the issue)

Comment: `netrw` is, err, _special_ code.  Consider posting a bug report to `vim_dev`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura - I thought `netrw` was maintained separately, but it [actually is in the main Vim repository](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/autoload/netrw.vim).  I guess, that, if no one has a similar issue I'll need to open a bug report and try to debug it myself.

Comment: You should ask those issues the maintainer of the file, but first test the latest [version](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#NETRW)

Comment: Report sent to `vim_dev` and to the maintainer of `netrw` (I believe at least, since I did not get a delivery failure), I'll keep the question updated as thing go forward.

Comment: I didn't see a message in `vim_dev` and also the moderation queue is empty. So it looks like it never appeared

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt It's [there](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/H-kLqWlH_Mg).